# postgres join tables with case condtion

Tags: postgresql

I need to join some tables by product id, the problem is that some products in different tables are not written in full format (full format is 12 digits whereas in some cases the same product is written with only the last 6 digits).

I tried to compare by the last 6 digits with `length(product_id,6)` but it's not a pure comparison due to some products sharing the same last 6 digits but they are not the same.

I tried to perform a check of the length of the product id and only, in that case, take compare the last 6 digits the result are reliable but it working too slowly.

**Methode 1**: normal join  fetch in 30-100 ms

```
SELECT * FROM
table_a ta 
  JOIN table_b tb ON ta.product_id = tb.product_id
```

**Methode 2**: join by last 6 digits fetch in 100-200 ms but ~10% are fake join

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a ta 
  JOIN table_b tb ON right(ta.product_id,6) = right(tb.product_id,6)
```

**Methode 3**: join by last 6 digits only if the length of product id is not equal,data is reliable but fetch around **30 seconds**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a ta 
  JOIN table_b tb ON
                     CASE 
                       WHEN LENGTH(ta.product_id) <> LENGTH(tb.product_id) 
                         THEN right(ta.product_id,6) = right(tb.product_id,6) 
                       ELSE ta.product_id = tb.product_id    
                     END
```

Why does using case conditions make it so slow? How do you suggest I compare those tables? I'm pretty sure there is another method that is not familiar to me yet.

Comment: You didn't show the execution plans, but the reason is very likely that if your join condition is not an equality comparison, the optimizer can only choose a nested loop join, which is slow with big tables and sequential scans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I do not have to say: having distinct values to represent the same product is bad design; the one thing you should do is correct that.
I will set that point aside for the rest of my answer though.

**Method 2** is the better candidate for modification, I will explain below why **Method 3** cannot be salvaged.
You have already written than the last 6 characters of `product_id` must be equal. We will simply add that `product_id` must be equal (all characters) or that their length must be different.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b
ON RIGHT(table_a.product_id, 6) = RIGHT(table_b.product_id, 6)
AND (
    table_a.product_id = table_b.product_id
    OR LENGTH(table_a.product_id) <> LENGTH(table_b.product_id)
)
```

---

Some additional notes:

1. Have you created a suitable index to perform the `JOIN`? Even though **Method 2** does not look too bad in terms of performance, you should probably do:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON table_a (RIGHT(product_id, 6));
   CREATE INDEX ON table_b (RIGHT(product_id, 6));
   ```
2. About the performance of **Method 3**:
   The `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ...` is probably immensely inefficient. The worst part is the `WHEN` that will try to join probably way more records than your expect.
   Example: `100000123456` in `table_a` will be joined with all 6-character-long ids from `table_b`; you have detected what you call "10% fake join" in cases like `200000123456` but the vast majority of the pairs tested are just random garbage like `654873`. Your `CASE` forces the evaluation of that garbage, hence the huge performance cost.
3. You are talking about digits in your question but based on the functions you use, I can see the columns are not integer_based types. I recommend you try converting the type of `product_id` to `bigint`.
   The last 6 digits are `MOD(product_id, 1000000)` and the `LENGTH` can be replaced by a comparison `product_id >= 1000000`.
   Make sure you test it before you actually make the change on the real tables.
4. I repeat myself but the correct way to solve your issue is by ensuring `product_id` is in 12-digit format everywhere. You should do a massive `UPDATE` using the query above.